# Analyzing Integral of a product using Cauchy Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if the functions $g,h:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, with $h(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then there is a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that
                  $\int_a^bh(x)g(x)dx=g(c)\int_a^bh(x)dx$.

At first I tried to use the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, by letting $A(x) =\int_a^xh(t)g(t)dt$ and $B(x) =\int_a^xh(t)dt$.  Then by CMVT, we have that there exists a point $c$ such that 
$$\frac{ \int_a^bh(x)g(x)dx }{ \int_a^bh(x)dx}= \frac{h(c)g(c)}{h(c)}=g(c) $$, and the result follows But this only holds if $h(x)$ is never $0$, which we dont have.  So is this the wrong way to do this?

Comment: Combine expression in the second line of the prompt to get a better feel of what you are trying to show.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying Rod?

Comment: Actually the extended mean value theorem says $g'(c)[f(b)-f(a)] = f'(c)[g(b)-g(a)]$ with c between a and b, which gives you your result directly.  The ratio only applies when one of the derivatives is not 0.

Comment: @RRL Well, the extended mean theorem that we proved has $g'(x) \neq 0$ and is stated as a ratio

Comment: I can show you the proof in the answer which shows that the cross multiplied form is the primary result -- if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following form of the extended mean value theorem.  If $A$ and $B$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and have  derivatives in $(a,b)$ , then there exists $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that

$$A'(c)[B(b)-B(a)] = B'(c)[A(b)-A(a)]$$

Proof.

Apply Rolle's Theorem to

$$\phi(x) = [A(x)-A(a)](B(b)-B(a)]- [B(x)-B(a)](A(b)-A(a)]$$

where $\phi(a) = \phi(b) = 0$.  We get $\phi'(c) = 0$ for some c in the interval.

Comment: Even if you use that trick how can you cancel $h(c)$ from both sides unless you know that $h(c) \neq 0\ $?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this textbook on page 139. What you're trying to prove is Theorem 3.3.7 (First Mean Value Theorem for Integrals).  A proof is there.  I'm not sure if you can get CMVT to work on this, but if you're not satisfying all the conditions of a theorem, you can't use it.

http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF

Comment: it is better if you come up with a different proof rather than posting someone's proof.

Comment: Thank you for the reference